# How to Zoom to fit a paperJS canvas

Tags: paperjs

I have multiple diagrams on a paperJS project. I want to display a smaller version that can fit a box. Say 500px X 350px. Now how can I zoom in or zoom out to fit the diagram in best possible way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can scale the group of items to make them fit in a given box.
There is a convenient method to do that: [item.fitBounds()](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#fitbounds-rectangle).

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/lZDBDoIwDIZfZdkFiLjgddzk6sHEo3gYo8hkbqQMiCG8uwzjwXiiSdP+7d98SSdqxBMop5cGnKxpTKUtvTYwkrNwNcsUSg3hlGNuyBISjAPkZFAwso8ge3JIkvjrQFGqvuM/s0ppnVltl8PAojB3CPxqjlJffG4C7jYBC93/4Vq0D5COCenUACfxAmSVckfbm7ILV1ax9lG6PKVAEE1rlXEd5dfb/AY=) demonstrating the solution.

```
new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center - 100,
    radius: 100,
    fillColor: 'orange'
});

new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center + 100,
    radius: 100,
    fillColor: 'blue'
});

project.activeLayer.fitBounds(view.bounds);
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Sasensi. 
Just what I needed for my project. 
Thanks Again :)